# HTML5 websockets and proxy configs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, proxy, websocket

I am using Debian 7 and browser Google Chrome (35).
When I am trying to pass echo test on [websockets.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)
there is an error in console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://echo.websocket.org/?encoding=text' failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame.
```

My PC is behind the proxy with Squid 3, but another users behind the same proxy can passing echo tests on [websockets.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) (squid configs are the same for each user).

How can I debug this issue?

I have turned off all my reverse proxy servers (nginx, apache)

If i write the following code in my Google chrome console :

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org/");
```

Then I can not see any frames (there is no handshacking phase) in the network page (Google chrome dev tools).

**UPDATE:**

The interesting thing, that websockets connection working for me with the latest version of the Iceweasel browser (Firefox), but it does not work with Google Chrome or Chromium.

I am starting Google Chrome with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --proxy-server="http://172.16.20.12:4554"
```

What else can be done? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The handshaking are not frames, is just plain HTTP. If you initiated a Websocket connection, and the server returns a HTTP 101 Switching Protocols response, that is the handshake.

Have you tried with WSS:// rather than WS://?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, with wss the same situation. The interesting thing, that websockets connection working for me with the latest version of the Iceweasel browser (Firefox), but it does not work with Google Chrome or Chromium

Comment: That is odd, because that server does not implement any extension, so it should be the same. Please post the solution if you find it, this is interesting :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm fairly sure that this is a bug in Chrome. One thing you should check for though is that in your proxy settings that you do _not_ check the "Use this proxy for all protocols" checkbox. This will register your HTTP proxy as a SOCKS proxy and websockets will try to use that and fail. This was my problem some months ago but I fixed it and had websocket working in chrome for a while, but some weeks ago it stopped working. So as I say, probably a regression bug in Chrome on *NIX (this works on windows).

Comment: I can still confirm in 2022 that putting the proxy to the socks_proxy makes  certainwebsockets break. Thx @StFS, this saved me a lot of time :)